# Что надо прописать в jquery, чтобы выделялась активная ссылка?

Tags: jquery

Прописываю в стилях

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

и прописываю в js файле

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

в итоге должно получиться так- при нажатии на ссылку она становится активной и должна гореть красной, при нажатии на другую ссылку, уже нажатая должна гореть красной, а предыдущая гаснуть. Но в итоге это все работает только когда удаляется строчка $('a').removeClass('active') и тогда ссылки хотя бы начинают гореть при нажатии, но почему это происходит? Почему .removeClass вообще не работает? Как сделать правильно?

сам сайт tempest.beget.tech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В текущей реализации вы берёте данную ссылку - добавляете ей класс и сразу же его удаляете. 
Вам необходимо удалять у всех остальных ссылок.

```js
    $('a').on('click', function(event) {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active'); // Удаляем класс active у всех ссылок, у кого он проставлен.
        $(this).addClass('active'); // Текущему элементу проставляем класс active
    });
```

```css
    .active {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">123</a>
<a href="#">123</a>
<a href="#">123</a>
<a href="#">123</a>
```